# Automatically Start this workflow whenever an item is changed SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to send an automatic email when an item is changed and a Option Checkbox Field is selected.
The item will be edited multiple times so I want the worflow to trigger that email only once and not every time something is changed. I have tried the example here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/watch-this-run-a-workflow-when-a-specific-field-changes-HA010256419.aspx?CTT=1

However my problem is that I have six workflows intiated when an item is Changed. It works but it seems my Sharepoint Site has slowed down a great deal as there are six workflows in the background.

I deleted 4 of them to see if it made a difference and it did.
My sharepoint site is running on a normal speed.

I am trying to send out an automatic email whenever each of the departments complete their portion on the Item and select the checkbox for "Complete".

Thank you for your help.

PW

Comment: Can you merge all the workflows into one? maybe add each workflow function as workflow step of one ?

Answer (score 2):

Is your main issue getting the email to send once? Or the workflows slowing down your SharePoint?

To ensure the email only sends once why not add a hidden checkbox field called something like "Has email been sent?" Default is No.

The workflow would then need the following steps

- "Has email been sent?" = No
- Send email
- Set "Has email been sent?" to Yes